# #define for different screensizes- iPhone 4 and iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor

I am working on my app to optimize the screen for iPhone 5. How could I use #define for two different screen sizes.

For iphone 5 screen I will use  below values:

```
 #define ACTIVITY_RECT_X 14
 #define ACTIVITY_RECT_Y 70
```

For iphone 4 screen I will use  below values:

```
 #define ACTIVITY_RECT_X 23
 #define ACTIVITY_RECT_Y 80
```

Comment: You don't. `#define` is a compile-time directive. Detecting the device is a runtime requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

if(IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    //Do something in respect of iphone 5
}
else
{
    //Do something in respect of iphone4s,iphone4 ,etc
}
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Use this as :

```
#define IS_IPHONE ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
#define IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 [[UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds].size.height >= 568.0f
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( IS_IPHONE && IS_HEIGHT_GTE_568 )
```

Ex :

```
 NSLog(@"Height  : %f",IS_IPHONE_5?80:60);
```

Hope it helps you.